# Building an index from an attribute

Tags: ios, swift, loops, dictionary, data-structures

I have a simple meetup class

```
class Meetup {
  var title: String
  var date: String
}
```

And an array of meetups fetched from meetup.com called `meetups`.

I would like to organize these meetups by date, in a dictionary: `[String, [Meetup]]` where the string is the date.

Here is my implementation

```
func buildDateMeetupDict(meetups: [Meetup]) -> [String, [Meetup]] {

    var dateMeetupDict = [String: [Meetup]]()

    for meetup in meetups {
        for var meetupsByDay in dateMeetupDict {
            if meetupsByDay.day == meetup.day {
                meetupsByDay.meetupArray.append(meetup)
            } else {
                let newMeetupDay = [meetup.day, [meetup]]
                dateMeetupDict.append(newMeetupDay)
            }
        }
    }
    return dateMeetupDict
}
```

It works, but is supremely inefficient, and feels and looks equally ghetto.

How do I pull an attribute from objects in an array and build an index based on that attribute, efficiently?

Comment: Where are your dictionaries? `[String, [Meetup]]()` is not a dictionary (I don't really know what it is; I'm surprised it compiles).

Comment: "but is supremely inefficient" How so? It seems obviously a great way to do it. What's the problem?

Comment: @matt you're right there was a typo.

Comment: Don't type. Copy and paste!

Comment: @matt Problem is it doesn't feel right. I was thinking maybe there was a better practice way of doing it, with some more more relevant language features that I'd be oblivious to. (answering second comment -- will copy+paste fno)

Comment: @matt is this how you would do it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would do it almost exactly as you are doing it. After all, you're only looping once thru the array.

I think you might want to express the algorithm a little more clearly. Your choice for each Meetup is:

- if the key doesn't exist, create it and make its value an array with this Meetup in it;
- if the key does exist, append this meetup to its value array.

I think we can say that very plainly, as follows:

```
// here's a test class
// [Note: I used `id` instead of `date`, but it's still just a string...]
class Meetup : CustomStringConvertible {
    var id: String
    var title: String
    init(id:String, title:String) {
        self.id = id; self.title = title
    }
    var description: String {
        return "\(self.id)/\(self.title)"
    }
}

// here's a test array of Meetups
let meetups : [Meetup] = [
    Meetup(id:"one", title:"Howdy"),
    Meetup(id:"two", title:"Hello"),
    Meetup(id:"two", title:"Bonjour"),
    Meetup(id:"one", title:"Namaste")
]

// and here's our actual code!
var dict = [String:[Meetup]]()
for meetup in meetups {
    let val = dict[meetup.id]
    dict[meetup.id] = val == nil ? [meetup] : val! + [meetup]
}
```

Now let's prove that it worked:

```
print(dict) // ["one": [one/Howdy, one/Namaste], "two": [two/Hello, two/Bonjour]]
```

So we've ended up with a dictionary whose keys are the original `id`s (your dates) and whose value for each `id` is an array of the Meetups with that `id`.

Comment: yeahhhh this is what I'm talking about ! What do I google to find how this part works `dict[meetup.id] = val == nil ? [meetup] : val! + [meetup]
`

Comment: Or wait is this just a sneaky implementation of nil coalescing operator??

Comment: @EricJohnson Do you know about `?:` "ternary" operator? http://www.apeth.com/swiftBook/ch05.html#_conditional_evaluation

Comment: Roughly did, but now I do. Also is this `dict[meetup.id] = val == nil` saying "assign `val` to `dict[meetup.id]` and compare it to `nil`"?

Comment: No. The whole line says: "If `val` is nil, assign `[meetup]` to `dict[meetup.id]`. If `val` is not nil, assign `val! + [meetup]` to `dict[meetup.id]`.

Comment: Got it. Thanks for the useful info. Will be sneaking this into much more code than was expected....

Comment: Haha just realized the contradiction "Roughly did, but now I do, Also........." XD